# Cannot resolve method 'recreate()' in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, recreate

recreate() cant be resolved in fragment activity.

```
mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {


                if( i==0 )
                {setLocale("per");
                    recreate();}


                if( i==1 )
                {setLocale("en");
                    recreate();}

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

I use this method in fragment activity as below:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentArguments {
```

Comment: `recreate()` is a method in `Activity`, not `Fragment`. I think you might be confusing and/or conflating those things.

Comment: I know but which method can be use in fragment

Comment: call getActivity().recreate() if you want to recreate your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recreate method in a Fragment. Its a method inherited from an Activity. If you want the recreate the Activity from the fragment, you can call

```
getActivity().recreate();
```

If you want to reload just the Fragment, you can detach the fragment and then attach it again like this.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .detach(YourFragment.this)
    .attach(YourFragment.this)
    .commit();
```